# Spark Structured Stream Scalability and Duplicates Issue

Tags: apache-spark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, databricks, spark-structured-streaming, azure-eventhub

I am using Spark Structured Streaming on Databricks Cluster to extract data from Azure Event Hub, process it, and write it to snowflake using ForEachBatch with Epoch_Id/ Batch_Id passed to the foreach batch function.

My code looks something like below:

```
ehConf = {}
ehConf['eventhubs.connectionString'] = sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils.encrypt(EVENT_HUB_CONNECTION_STRING)
ehConf['eventhubs.consumerGroup'] = consumergroup

# Read stream data from event hub
spark_df = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("eventhubs") \
  .options(**ehConf) \
  .load()
```

Some transformations...

Write to Snowflake

```
def foreach_batch_function(df, epoch_id):
       df.write\
            .format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME)\
            .options(**sfOptions)\
            .option("dbtable", snowflake_table)\
            .mode('append')\
            .save()

processed_df.writeStream.outputMode('append').\
    trigger(processingTime='10 seconds').\
    option("checkpointLocation",f"checkpoint/P1").\
    foreachBatch(foreach_batch_function).start()
```

Currently I am facing 2 issues:

1. When node failure occurs. Although on spark official web, it is mentioned that when one uses ForeachBatch along with epoch_id/batch_id during recovery form node failure there shouldn't be any duplicates, but I do find duplicates getting populated in my snowflake tables. Link for reference: [Spark Structured Streaming ForEachBatch With Epoch Id][1].
2. I am encountering errors a.)**TransportClient: Failed to send RPC RPC 5782383376229127321 to /30.62.166.7:31116: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException** and b.)**TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 1560 on 30.62.166.7: worker decommissioned: Worker Decommissioned** very frequently on my databricks cluster. No matter how many executors I allocate or how much executors memory I increase, the clusters reaches to max worker limit and I receive one of the two error with duplicates being populated in my snowflake table after its recovery.

Any solution/ suggestion to any of the above points would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`foreachBatch` is by definition not idempotent because when currently executed batch fails, then it's retries, and partial results could be observed, and this is matching your observations. Idempotent writes in `foreachBatch` are [applicable](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/idempotent-writes.html) only for Delta Lake tables, not for all sink types (in some cases, like, Cassandra, it could work as well).  I'm not so familiar with Snowflake, but maybe you can implement something similar to other database - write data into a temporary table (each batch will do an overwrite) and then merge from that temporary table into a target table.

Regarding 2nd issue - it looks like you're using autoscaling cluster - in this case, workers could be decommissioned because cluster managers detects that cluster isn't fully loaded.  To avoid that you can disable autoscaling, and use fixed size cluster.